# MySQL query from PHP returns incorrect results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal-7

My MySQL table "tracks" has these two fields:

```
Id (Int)
Name (Varchar 255)
```

The values are:

```
1   Day 1
2   Day 2
3   Day 3
```

I am trying to retrieve all the tracks from PHP using this functions:

```
function getTracks() {
    $query = sprintf('select * from tracks');
    return contentRetrieverDataBaseQuery($query)->fetchAssoc();
}

function contentRetrieverDataBaseQuery($query) {
    $settings = contentRetrieverGetSettings();
    Database::addConnectionInfo('contentRetriever', 'default', $settings['database_connection']);
    db_set_active('contentRetriever');
    $result = db_query($query);
    db_set_active();
    return $result;
}
```

Running `select * from event_tracks` on phpmyadmin I get the results correctly.

When I do this:

```
$tracks = getTracks();
foreach ($tracks as $track) {
  echo $track['name'];
}
```

I get as an output "1D", which is the Id and the first letter of the Name.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Corrected the name of the database

Comment: nowhere inside your `contentRetrieveDataBaseQuery` do you define `$result`...

Comment: @MarcB `$result = db_query($query);`

Comment: @camil: remind me to go see my optometrist...

Comment: You say your table is called `tracks`, but your queries are for `event_tracks`. Is that a mistake in your question or in your code? :) If that doesn't help, the problem is likely to be in one of the functions you didn't show us... You could try adding `var_dump()`s to see what's going on.

Comment: Ok, now that my eyes are open, most likely the `->fetchAssoc()` is returning a SINGLE row of data, which means that `$tracks` is a single level array, and `$track['name']` is taking the string value in $track and trying to treat it as a string, meaning `$foo = 'bar'; echo $foo[1]` outputs `a`. - `['name']` will be parsed down to `[0]`.

Comment: Use `fetchAll` instead of `fetchAssoc` to get all the results as a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Exactly, please make your comment an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->fetchAssoc()` invariably returns a single row of query results, meaning that your array is a single record, and your loop will be putting that row's string values into `$track`. You then use `$track` as if it was an array, producing the following code equivalent:

```
$arr = array('abc', 'def'); // your one row of query results.
foreach($arr as $value) {
   // $value is now 'abc';
   echo $value['name']; // parsed/executed as $value[0];
  // output is 'a'
}
```

Strings can be treated as arrays of characters, which is why PHP didn't complain about `$tracks['name']`. It simply treated as `['name']` as a goofy attempt at using a non-numeric array index, and converted it to `0`.